# Is inheritance handled differently in jupyter?

Tags: python, inheritance, jupyter-notebook

This sounds as if it should be really simple but I do not quite understand how inheritance applies in jupyter notebooks.

I created the following class as a subclass of ipywidgets.HTML. I have tested that this does what I want and for the purpose of this question, what it's exactly doing is irrelevant

```
class Icon(ipywidgets.HTML):
    """font-awesome icon widget by intercepting ipywidgets.HTML.value"""
    def __init__(self, icon, *args, cat='fa', style='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.icon = icon
        self.css_style = style
        if not self.css_style.strip().endswith(';'):
            self.css_style += ';'
        self.cat = cat
        self.value = self.html()

    def html(self, style=''):
        html = '<i class="{} fa-{}" style="{}"></i>'
        styled_icon = html.format(self.cat, self.icon, self.css_style + style)
        return styled_icon
```

When I define this class in a Jupyter notebook, then instanciate it in another cell, e.g by:

```
icon = Icon('square')
icon
```

The HTML widget displays as expected.
However, when I put this class definition in `customwidgets.py` and use `from customwidgets import *` the exact same jupyter cell as above gives the following output message :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-176522f37eb8> in <module>()
----> 1 icon = Icon('square')

~/path/to/customwidgets.py in __init__(self, icon, cat, style, *args, **kwargs)
     13     """font-awesome icon widget by intercepting ipywidgets.HTML.value"""
     14     def __init__(self, icon, *args, cat='fa', style='', **kwargs):
---> 15         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     16         self.icon = icon
     17         self.css_style = style

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

How come that the behavior is different in one case with respect to the other?

Comment: Interesting. What debugging options have you tried? When you import `Icon`, What is `Icon.mro()`? What happens if you change `super().__init__(...)` to `super(Icon, self).__init__(...)`? My guess is this something to do with the fact that `HTML` is not a normal class, but an instance of the metaclass `traitlets.traitlets.MetaHasTraits`.

Comment: I apologize ... odly enough I find myself unable to reproduce the error again ... I do not know what happened. I know however that `super(Icon, self).__init__` does not help, as this was what I was trying before.